# Java program produces different output when code is run from within Eclipse compared to the exported runnable jar on Windows 11

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, character-encoding

When I run the following java code from within Eclipse on Windows 11 I get the expected result: Created a More “Positive” or “Negative”

When I export the same code to a runnable jar and run it, I get a bad result (surrounded by question marks): Created a More ?Positive? or ?Negative?

What I've tried so far:

1. Starting the exported jar from command prompt using: `java -jar myprogram.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
2. Writing `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")` at the beginning of the main method.

One can also reproduce the issue online by:

1. Pasting the Java code at: [Programiz online compiler](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/)
   Results in the ***bad*** response: Created a More ?Positive? or ?Negative?
2. Pasting the Java code at: [Jdoodle online java-compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/)
   Results in the ***good*** response:  Created a More “Positive” or “Negative”

Below is the Java code. How can I fix it?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


    byte[] bytes = {32, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 100, 32, 97, 32, 77, 111, 114, 101, 32, -30, -128, -100, 80, 111, 115, 105, 116, 105, 118, 101, -30, -128, -99, 32, 111, 114, 32, -30, -128, -100, 78, 101, 103, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, -30, -128, -99, 32};
    String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: Check your terminal's encoding. Your java code will probably emit UTF-8, but if the terminal cannot display the characters it the question marks may pop up.

Comment: The question marks indicate you are running your program in an environment without the **glyphs** necessary to display the intended characters. There is nothing wrong with your program. Or with Windows. You are missing a **font**. That is it.

Comment: Yes, probably a font that doesn't support U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK

Comment: This depends on the environment. For example, on `programiz.com`, executing `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` produces `ANSI_X3.4-1968` for whatever reason. So software taking this serious can not encode non-ASCII characters. On the other hand, just ignoring the encoding via `System.out.write(bytes);` produces the intended string. So the encoding happens to be UTF-8, actually. On the other hand, this won’t work with the Windows console.